# Amazon S3 assets randomly blocked by CORS policy

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

This one has me stumped. I am using an Amazon S3 bucket to store uploaded images that I then access later when a specific page loads. I've run into this error before:

> Access to Image at 'my S3 image url' from origin 'https://uncvrd.co'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'https://uncvrd.co' is therefore not allowed access.

Understandable, this happened on my last project too, and the fix was to make sure I add these settings to my S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::unlink/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(unlink is the name of my bucket)

And then my CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://uncvrd.co</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I use an identical setup on my other S3 bucket for my other site and it works flawlessly.

Thing is here, it works **most of the time** but on random occasions (and I see it more on mobile than on desktop), I get the CORS blocked error...it is not consistent! This is extremely difficult to replicate and I don't know what I'm missing.

I am using .NET MVC and I store the S3 url in database, then on page load I simply call the url from the controller and pass it through in the model to display in my cshtml page.

According to my network tab, it is trying to load the image twice and it cancels?

[image]

EDIT: Might this have something to do with image caching?? I just cleared my cache and reloaded and now the image displays

**EDIT 2: Attempting Workaround #2 with differing url params:**

In my HTML I now have: `<img crossorigin="anonymous" id="album-img" src="@Model.Album.ImageURL?x-request=html" />`

But how do I access the above URL without the params in javascript? With the following:

```
$("#album-img").imagesLoaded(function () {
         //if I add just the image url to the variable below it does not work
         var sourceImage = document.getElementById("album-img");
         var colorThief = new ColorThief();
         var red = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage)[0];
         var green = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage)[1];
         var blue = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage)[2];

         $('#platform-container').css({
             background: "linear-gradient(rgba(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ",1.0), #2a2a2a 296px)"
         });

     });
```

Comment: If you are referencing the same image URL from both CORS and non-CORS contexts, there's a [behavioral anomaly in S3](https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161) that may be relared.  This is sometimes incorrectly assumed to be a problem with CloudFront since the two are often used together, but it is an S3 issue.  An S3 bucket with CORS enabled *should* return a `Vary: Origin` header in non-CORS responses, but it doesn't.  This impacts Chrome for sure, and possibly other browsers.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the response, just read through your answer. So if I understand correctly, this is an issue because I have an initial call to the URL to load the image, and then once the image is loaded, I run a small javascript that calculates the average color of the image and uses that as the background color for the page. This second access to the S3 image is causing the CORS error? I might be way off, but that's the only thing I can think of

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  If the first access is `<img src= ...>`, that doesn't require CORS.  That response will be cached.  When you try to make a JS access to the same image, that requires CORS.  Because `Vary:` doesn't indicate that a CORS request would change the response, the browser doesn't bother making one -- it throws the error based on the fact that the cached response doesn't have the necessary headers to allow the cross-origin access.  S3 blames Chrome, but unfortunately, Chrome is quite correct with this behavior.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm attempting your second workaround since I do not use Cloudfront, however, I am struggling to figure out how to access the url from javascript as it is not an html image element. Maybe the alternative is to store the url as a hidden element? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Oh, interesting... so you aren't deliberately accessing the image twice by URL, already.  This may be a different case with a similar cause.  An easier workaround/test is to try is set `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` on the object in the S3 console, clear your browser cache, and see what happens.  If that doesn't work around the issue, this might be something different.

Comment: What is the recommended protocol for doing this? I have the exact same scenario happening - image loaded, then JS loads it into a canvas for DOM manipulation and sometimes errors out.

Should the `<img>` tag call have something specified, or some the JS call?

Comment: Hey @EricHolmes what worked for me was the second hackaround from the link the first commenter posted!

Comment: @JordanLewallen thank you! I'm reading it now :)

Comment: @EricHolmes no problem, good luck!